# Making javascript change an html element when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a disabled button [a]. I have a form that does not have any buttons in it [b]. I also have javascript to handle this [c]. I need to make it so that when the user has completed the form (next to action and method attribute)[b], it makes the button [a] enabled.

[a]

```
<button id="firstbtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" disabled>Sign up</button>
```

[b]

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
  <script src="https://button.stripe.com/v1/button.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
    data-amount=53500
    data-description="One Wilde quote"
    data-label="Buy"></script>
</form>
```

[c]

```
<script>

function disableElement()
{
document.getElementById("firstbtn").disabled=false;
}

</script>
```

I could have a button that has the following attribute: [d]-->onclick="disableElement()". As you can see, the form does not have a button. When the user clicks on the form, they have to fill out a credit card form. They submit "Buy" and then the code goes to the action="register.php" code. I need it to not go there, but simply update the button to enabled using [d].

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a javascript changing an element in php with a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484250/making-a-javascript-changing-an-element-in-php-with-a-form)

Comment: I rephrased it since no one understood what I meant popnoodles. I am also asking a different question.

Comment: I see. I'm confused why you have a block of javascript inside a form.

Comment: Use jquery validation engine or some other to do what you want.  Otherwise you just have to trigger the disabled=false when the user reaches the last element.

Comment: popnoodles, that is stripe's "buy" button. I need to make the onclick="disableElement()" happen at the same time as the form action="" is completed.

Comment: Go to www.stribbly.com/toolbox/register.php to see both of these

Comment: @popnoodles do you know what I can do?

Comment: I've got it. I made the action in the form ( action="javascript: disableElement()" )